# ignore columns in SSDL for entity-framework

Tags: entity-framework, ssdl

We use dotconnect for Oracle and have three schemas (Master, Staging and Prod) in our database. We have three SSDL files, one corresponding to each schema. Until now all the schemas had the same table structure, but now we have less number of columns in one of the table in one schema. We have one Data Model for all three schemas and use the different SSDL files when querying the corresponding schema. Is there a way to ignore columns in the SSDL file (or elsewhere), so we can continue using a single Data Model?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, why does the one table in the one schema have fewer columns? Why not fix that problem? Or, if the extra columns contain debug/test related information, then move them to a different table so the underlying table has the same structure in all three versions.

Comment: The Prod schema is used as the database for another application and it needs to remain oblivious to the new columns. Hence the new/extra columns are not added to the Prod schema.

Answer (score 0):

We have answered you at our forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=27778.